# oracle Insert rows for speicific missing values

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table below with some info.

```
ID     IDZONE    IDVALUE     RANK
A1     ZONE-1    100         1
B1     ZONE-1    100         1
C1     ZONE-1    100         1
C1     ZONE-2    200         2
C1     ZONE-3    300         3
C1     ZONE-4    400         4
C1     ZONE-5    500         5
n rows----
```

I wanted to re display the table to make sure every ID should contains RANK value 1-5 like below( null/0 for missing values).

```
ID     IDZONE    IDVALUE     RANK
A1     ZONE-1    100         1
A1     null      0           2
A1     null      0           3
A1     null      0           4
A1     null      0           5
B1     ZONE-1    100         1
B1     null      0           2
B1     null      0           3
B1     null      0           4
B1     null      0           5 
C1     ZONE-1    100         1
C1     ZONE-2    200         2
C1     ZONE-3    300         3
C1     ZONE-4    400         4
C1     ZONE-5    500         5
n rows------
```

Tried left join by using separate WITH clause on RANK column but nothing works out. Please suggest how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in oracle, you can use this technique to create the artificial data you need.   Then join to it, and keep the artificial data that is not in your primary set.

```
SELECT LEVEL n
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Comment: yeah I tried same by putting the logic above in WITH clause. But the join condition baseTable.Rank=N always returns data from base table only(tried left/right join as well), not seeing null values for missing data.

Comment: Show me what you have

Comment: something similar to what you have suggested.

`with DUMMY_ROW as(
select ID, null as IDZONE, 100 as IDVALUE,1 as rank from IDTABLE
UNION
select ID, null as IDZONE, 200 as IDVALUE,2 as rank from IDTABLE
UNION
select ID, null as IDZONE, 300 as IDVALUE,3 as rank from IDTABLE
UNION
select ID, null as IDZONE, 400 as IDVALUE,4 as rank from IDTABLE
UNION
select ID, null as IDZONE, 500 as IDVALUE,5 as rank from IDTABLE
)
select s.id, nvl(t.IDZONE,s.IDZONE),nvl(t.IDVALUE,s.IDVALUE),s.rank
from DUMMY_ROW s left join IDTABLE t  on (t.rank=s.rank and t.id=s.id) order by id,rank;`

Comment: I don't see you using connect by to generate the artificial data.